# Ошибка в build.gradle моего FirebaseChat

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Приветствую.

Делал проект по видео: https://youtu.be/WOX7fqGKvog
Все отлично, компилируется, но при запуске крашится. Runtime-ошибка.

В проекте только 1 строка подчеркнута красным и я думаю что ошибка из-за нее:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Текст ошибки: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1., 25.0.0., 23.4.0. Example include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.0.

Полный код build.gradle (app):

```
/* apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
//    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.fandroid.firebasechat"
//        minSdkVersion 14
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
*/

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
//    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.fandroid.firebasechat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.andoid.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Add Library
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
//    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку. Я уже пробовал изменять версии в разных местах, на те, что доступны, но не помогло...

**UPD.** Вставил оригинальный код с текстовой версии урока, но не помогло:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.fandroid.firebasechat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Add Library
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Она же у вас закомментирована

Comment: Ошибка не в зависимостях. Это просто варнинг. Можно проигнорировать. Приведите логи ошибки при запуске

Comment: Вставил оригинальный код с текстовой версии урока. Та же проблема. Логи ошибки? Это в Android Monitor > Errors?

Comment: @Hinc, ну... Вроде оно. LogCat надо смотреть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё же хорошо написано у вас:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

А вы используете разные версии:

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
compile 'com.andoid.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

И так далее.

Проследите чтобы версии разных библиотек, взятых из `com.android.support` не отличались, как и описывается в ошибке.

Comment: вставил оригинальный код с текстовой версии урока. Та же проблема.